# Javascript event.preventDefault() not working on Safari, but working on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, recaptcha

Hi, guys:
For some resaon the event.preventDefault() function not working on safari browser, but working fine on Google Chrome and Firefox. What I want to do is prevent the user to submit the form, unless they finish the google reCAPTCHA(Version 2). Please let me know how can I fix this issue. Appreciate you help.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <h4>
    <center></center>
  </h4>
  <form action="http://g/r59jr" method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="form-group">


        <label for="firstname">First Name<small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" title="Required" alt="Required"></i></small></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="First" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo set_value('First'); ?>" autocomplete="given-name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname"> Last Name<small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" title="Required" alt="Required"></i></small></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Last" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo set_value('Last'); ?>" autocomplete="given-name" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;" for="email">Email<small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" title="Required" alt="Required"></i></small></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;" for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" name="Phone" autocomplete="cellphone" value="<?php echo set_value('Phone'); ?>">
        <span><small></small></span>
      </div>


    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="row top30 ">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="agreeTOS">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTOS" name="agreeTOS" value='1' <?php echo set_checkbox('agreeTOS','1'); ?> required>&nbsp;I agree to the<a href="<?=site_url('legal/privacy_policy')?>"> Privacy Policy</a><small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" title="Required" alt="Required"></i></small>
                                        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row top30 ">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!--change-->
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6example.........."></div><br>

        <button type="submit" value="<?php echo set_value('Submit'); ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-primary btn-lg signup submit_information_request btn-block" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn">Sign-Up</button>
        </form>

        <!--change-->
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            $('#form').submit(function(event) {
              var verified = grecaptcha.getResponse();
              if (verified.length === 0) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            });
          });
        </script>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to add `return false;` to terminate your callback?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.